# Infinite product of rotation matrices

Tags: rotations, infinite-product

Suppose we have a product
$$\vec v=\left(\vec x^T \cdot R(\vec\varphi_1)\cdot R(\vec\varphi_2)\cdot ...\right)^T,$$
where $R(\vec\varphi_i)$ is a matrix of rotation by $3D$ angle $|\vec\varphi_i|$ around $\vec \varphi_i$.

Assuming that this product of rotation matrices converges, how can one, given $\vec\varphi_i\forall i$, find $\vec v$ or the resulting matrix of transformation?

Comment: If the product converges then shouldn't the components of the matrices form convergent sequences?

Comment: @dezign Well they should... but I don't quite get what I gain from this fact.

Comment: @Ruslan Do we know that the product converges for all $x$, or just for a single vector $x$?

Comment: @ChrisCulter It converges for all x. I.e., transformation matrix elements converge.

Comment: The posting didn't say "for all $x$".  Might not the sequence converge for one particular value of $x$ even though the sequence of matrices does not converge?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, in my case the product of rotation matrices must converge. I've edited the question to explicitly say this.

Comment: Are allowing the vectors $\phi_i$ to be different every time? Are we in 3d?

Comment: @Maesumi $\vec\varphi_i$ are generally different for different $i$, if you mean this (otherwise the product of matrices couldn't converge). Yes, we are in $3D$.

Comment: The issue of infinite product of matrices has been an active area of [research](http://www.math.duke.edu/~ingrid/publications/LAA_161_1992.pdf). Even for a fixed set of two by two matrices it is nontrivial. Perhaps rotation matrices provide some simplification, but I would guess it would be a substantial result.

Comment: The composition law of rotation matrices is [straightforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2627462/362193) --Rodrigues 1840. You want an efficient computational algorithm for the sequence of such rotations?

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes, I'm looking for an algorithm (or maybe even closed-form result) for the limit of this infinite product of rotations.

Comment: Suppose there is no limit. Look at the earth: it keeps on spinning and spinning ad infinitum.